# When quotients of polynomial rings are isomorphic to polynomial rings?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

> This might be a silly question but is there a criterion for when the quotient of $k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ by some ideal is isomorphic to a polynomial ring?

For instance $k[X,Y]/\langle Y \rangle \simeq k [X]$ but $k[X,Y]/\langle Y^2 \rangle$ is not a polynomial ring.

Comment: An obvious necessary condition is that the ideal has to be prime, which is enough to rule out $\langle Y^2\rangle$.

Comment: And the quotient ring has to be regular; check out http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79956/jacobian-criterion-for-smoothness-of-schemes

Comment: I doubt that there are is a (useful and nontrivial) criterion. One could use it to attack the wide open Zariski cancellation problem.

Comment: There are probably no such non-trivial criterion. One deep result is the Abhyankar-Moh theorem which says that  $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/f$ is the polynomial ring in one variable if and only if there is a $\mathbb{C}$- algebra automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ which transforms $f$ into a variable.

Comment: If the ideal $I$ is generated by homogeneous polynomials, then the condition is that $I$ is generated by polynomials of degree one.

Comment: Martin: I'm not sure the cancellation problem is so wide open any more.  Check out http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0483.

Comment: The statement of arxiv.org/abs/1208.0483 is in positive characteristic. But it certainly makes the conjecture unlikely to hold (for high enough dimension) in characteristic zero.

Comment: @Lev: interesting comment. Would your argument for failure in high dimension apply to the Jacobian conjecture too?

Comment: I am not an expert,  but I have not heard about cancellation conjecture being related to the Jacobian conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree that there is probably no useful + nontrivial criterion, here's a simple one:

> **Proposition:** Let $R$ be a finitely generated domain over $k$. Then $R$ is a polynomial ring over $k$ iff some (equivalently, every minimal) set of $k$-algebra generators of $R$ has size $\operatorname{tr.deg}_k R$.

In fact, if any set of $k$-algebra generators has the "right size" ($= \operatorname{tr.deg}_k R$), then they form a transcendence basis over $k$, and there are no additional algebraic relations in $R$.

The proof is a standard trick in dimension theory: if $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ is a set of $k$-algebra generators with $n = \operatorname{tr.deg}_k R$, then by Noether normalization, $n = \dim R$. The map $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \twoheadrightarrow R$ sending $x_i \mapsto a_i$ is a surjection between domains of the same dimension, hence is an isomorphism.

To relate this to the defining ideal $I$ of $R$ (w.r.t. some given presentation $R \cong k[y_1, \ldots, y_m]/I$), one can rephrase the above by saying that $R$ is a polynomial ring iff $I$ is prime and $R$ can be generated as a $k$-algebra by $m - \operatorname{ht}(I)$ many elements.